# Error C2280; an issue with operator =(const Employee &) occurs while executing employees.erase()

Tags: c++, oop, vector, operator-overloading

The subject (I mean *overloading operators*, *default* and *copy constructors* etc.) is something new for me and I really don't get it. I tried to avoid it but it has got me anyway. I have a container `std::vector<Employee>` with objects. Even thought I don't use `= operator`

I get the error:
`C2280  'Employee &Employee::operator =(const Employee &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`.

The error stops occur if I remove the line `employees.erase(employees.begin() + 1);`

I've found out that is a common problem but still I can't find any solution. Please take a look at the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Employee
{
public:
    std::string name, profession;
    std::string current_task = "NONE";
    int id, age, warrings;

    std::vector<std::string>& tasks;

    Employee::Employee(std::vector<std::string>& tasks) : tasks(tasks)
    {
        warrings = 0;
    };

    virtual void AssignNewTask(std::string input_string)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++)
        {
            if (input_string == tasks[i])
            {
                current_task = input_string;
                std::cout << ">> Przydzielony nowy task!" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        }

        std::cout << input_string << "nie nalezy do listy obowiazkow " << profession << std::endl;
    }
};

class HR : public Employee
{
private:
    static std::vector<std::string> tasks;

public:
    HR::HR() : Employee(tasks)
    {
        Employee::profession = "HR Specialist";
    }
};

class Helpdesk : public Employee
{
private:
    static std::vector<std::string> tasks;

public:
    Helpdesk::Helpdesk() : Employee(tasks)
    {
        Employee::profession = "Helpdesk Technician";
    }
};

std::vector<std::string> HR::tasks = { "HR task" };
std::vector<std::string> Helpdesk::tasks = { "Helpdesk task" };

bool operator==(const Employee & obj, const std::string & std)
{
    if ((obj.name == std) || (std == obj.name))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Employee> employees;
    std::cout << "Welcome message" << std::endl;

    // it works
    employees.push_back(HR());
    employees.push_back(Helpdesk());

    // it also works
    employees.pop_back();
    employees.push_back(Helpdesk());

    // the issue occurs !
    employees.erase(employees.begin() + 1);

    system("pause");
}
```

I guess that I should overload a `= operator` but I even don't know how to begin. I've marked where the issue occurs.

Comment: What you're asking about is not nearly your biggest problem. `std::vector<Employee>` can only hold `Employee` objects, not any `HR` or `Helpdesk` objects.

Comment: Why not if it works?

Comment: It doesn't work. You're just not looking in enough detail yet to see in what way it doesn't work. When you call `employees.push_back(HR());`, you construct a new `Employee` object using its copy constructor, taking `HR()` as its argument, and only copying the `Employee` fields. It doesn't save any `HR` object. The easy way to see this go very badly wrong is adding a virtual method, and attempting to call that virtual method. You'll find that the base implementation gets called rather than the derived implementation.

Comment: So, even thought that a object changes its profession from `None` to `HR specialist` the object still belows to `Employee`?

Comment: @hvd so tell me: does the concept with `std::vector` is completely badly or can I fix it yet? The issue is about concept or implementation?

Comment: It's possible to fix that, for instance by holding a `vector<shared_ptr<Employee>>`, at which point you no longer need an `operator=` for your `Employee` class since `vector` will only be copying pointers to employees, not the employees themselves. Another approach could be to not have a separate class for `HR`, but keep it contained in `Employee`. Yet another approach could be to use `boost::variant`. It's too soon to say which approach is best for you based on just this question, you may want to read up on the advantages and disadvantages of each approach yourself.

Comment: I was thinking about it and I solved it using `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Employee>>`. The problem is pointers of type `Employee` have only access to functions which are part of the `Employee` object, not derived one. But I'll think about it, may I'll solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    std::string name, profession;
    std::string current_task = "NONE";
    int id, age, warrings;

    std::vector<std::string> *tasks; // <=== use a pointer

    Employee(std::vector<std::string>& tasks) : tasks(&tasks)
    {
        warrings = 0;
    };
```

You can't define a operator= since you can't assign a reference (tasks). Remove the reference and it will be all OK (maybe slower, but safer)

Comment: Ok, I know that without it the code will work, but I need assign a reference to achieve my goal. How can I replace it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use pointer in this case. Can u tell more about it?

Comment: Thanks you I understand the issue. I've solved it in another way. That what I done does not have any sense.